# Using remove() to delete array within an array

Tags: python

If I have an array of arrays (a matrix) in python, e.g.

```
my_array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3]]
```

and I would like to remove all instances of [1,2,3]

```
new_array = my_array.remove([1,2,3])
```

results in null. Is there a way to apply remove() to arrays within arrays in this way that would work, i.e. so that

```
new_array = [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: These are *lists*, not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3]]

# you can put your conditions
new_array = [arr for arr in my_array if [1,2,3] != arr]

print(new_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `remove()` doesn't return any value (returns None). Also, you have defined a list of list, not array. You should write it this way:-

```
my_array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3]]
count = my_array.count([1,2,3])  # returns 2
for i in range(count):
    my_array.remove([1,2,3])

print(my_array)
```

Output:-

```
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used python in some time, and was under the mistaken impression that remove() would return a list with the object removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and remove function to get the desired result

```
my_array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3]]

while([1,2,3] in my_array):
    my_array.remove([1,2,3])

print(my_array)
```